# Choosing base class template arguments based on derived class arguments

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming

I hope that the following description is relatively clear:

My present design has a class hierarchy similar to the following:

```
struct Base{
public:
    Base(Base* child) { children.add(child);}
protected:
    std::vector<Base*> children;
};

template< /* multiple typename T_n generated by Boost Preprocessor */ >
struct A : public Base{};

template <uint32_t N>
struct B : public Base{
public:
    B() : Base(new A< uint32_t, uint32_t, */ additional uint32_t arguments based on parameter N */ >() ){}    
};
```

The issue that I need to have N + 1 arguments of type uint32_t being passed to the constructor for A.

As noted above, I have used Boost Preprocessor in part of this class hierarchy.  I realize that it might be one of the possible solutions now to my issue.  However, my preference is to find a possibly better approach (I find Boost Preproccesor to be difficult to use -- definitely due to my lack of experience, I find it to be finicky and the code to be difficult to read).

I suspect that MPL can be used here, but I cannot see how that could be accomplished.

Any suggestions and assistance would be very much appreciated.  I do not mean to suggest that the design above is the best possible one and would also be open to suggestions on how to fix.  That being said, I would still like to have a solution based on the current design, at the very least for the purpose of educating myself in C++ and Boost.

Thanks in advance,

Shmuel

Comment: Read about the CRTP idiom. Or just create a size_t template parameter for the base class which takes N, and for base ctor use a tuple of N size_ts.

Comment: I am familiar with the CRTP idiom, but not sure how that would be applicable here.  The issue is not with the base class but with another derived class that is passed to Base (Decorator pattern).  Indeed, I agree that the design of A (with the variable length list of types) is not the ideal, but a lot of the codebase relies on it and I am reluctant to change it right now.

Answer (score 2):

So essentially you want `B<3>` to derive from `A<int, int, int>`? That can be arranged:

```
template <typename> struct BImpl;    // no definition

template <typename ...Args> struct BImpl<std::tuple<Args...>> : A<Args...> {};

template <int N> using B = BImpl<typename IntMaker<N>::type>;
```

Now you just need to create `IntMaker`, like so:

```
template <int N, typename ...Args>
struct IntMaker<N, Args...> : IntMaker<N - 1, int, Args...> {};

template <typename ...Args>
struct IntMaker<0, Args...>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```